# How to pass both regexp and replacement to Perl as a command line argument (@ARGV)

Tags: cmd

I have created a following program to illustrate the point in Perl:

```
use strict;

my $text       = (@ARGV >= 1) ? $ARGV[0] : "This is some random text.";
my $regexp     = (@ARGV >= 2) ? $ARGV[1] : "[A-Za-z]([^ ]+)";
my $replacment = (@ARGV >= 3) ? $ARGV[2] : '"$1"';
if (@ARGV > 0) {
    for (my $argIndex = 0; $argIndex < @ARGV; $argIndex++) {
        print "ARG [$argIndex]: \"$ARGV[$argIndex]\"\n";
    }
}

print "TEXT: \"$text\" ->\n";
$text =~ s/$regexp/$replacment/eeg;
print "      \"$text\"\n";
```

If I ran this program without a command line argument as `> perl regexp.pl` it works as it should.

```
TEXT: "This is some random text." ->
      "his s ome andom ext."
```

However, I want to pass **regexp** and **replacement** to Perl as a command line argument (@ARGV). So when I try executing the same program with a command line argument of: `> perl regexp.pl "This is some random text 2" "[A-Za-z]([^ ]+)" '"$1"'` on **Windows** Command Prompt, it does not work. I get the following result instead:

```
ARG [0]: "This is some random text 2"
ARG [1]: "[A-Za-z]([^ ]+)"
ARG [2]: "'$1'"
TEXT: "This is some random text 2" ->
      "$1 $1 $1 $1 $1 2"
```

As an additional information, using the same command line argument on **Linux** works as it should. So here are my questions,

1. How could I get it to work on **Windows** (what should I type for as a command line argument to get it to work)
2. If there is a way to get it to work on **Windows**, then why do I need to pass it that way?

Comment: So it's actually a `cmd` question how to get `"` in an argument, not a Perl one. Try escaping: `... "This is some random text." "[A-Za-z]([^ ]+)" "\"$1\""`

Comment: It is impossible to pass an argument string via `cmd.exe` to another executable which contains `"`. There is no possibility to escape a double quote to get it interpreted as literal character inside a double quoted argument string. But regular expression engines with Perl syntax support `\x22`  to define in a search/replace string a double quote character with its hexadecimal code value. This can be used here to pass the replace string `"$1"` as `"\x22$1\x22"` or just as `\x22$1\x22` as this argument string does not contain a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<>|``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works (as mentioned by sticky bit):

```
perl regexp.pl "This is some random text 2" "[A-Za-z]([^ ]+)" "\"$1\""
perl regexp.pl "This is some random text 2" "[A-Za-z]([^ ]+)" "$1"
perl regexp.pl "This is some random text 2" "[A-Za-z]([^ ]+)" $1
```

They all give:

```
TEXT: "This is some random text 2" ->
      "his s ome andom ext 2"
```

In order to replace with **double quotes**, the following works (as mentioned by Mofi):

```
perl regexp.pl "This is some random text 2" "[A-Za-z]([^ ]+)" "\"\x22$1\x22\""
```

They give:

```
TEXT: "This is some random text 2" ->
      ""his" "s" "ome" "andom" "ext" 2"
```